# MOXy JAXB is marshalling an @XMLValue unexpectedly

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

When attempting to marshall a string containing valid XML as an `@XmlValue` property of another object, the string is incorrectly encoded.

For the source string:

```
<person><nickname>Jughead</nickname></person>
```

The marshaller returns:

```
&lt;person>&lt;nickname>Jughead&lt;/nickname>&lt;/person>
```

(Note that `<` is correctly escaped as `&lt;` but `>` is not escaped.)

This problem seems to be implementation dependent as the same code works as expected (returning `&lt;person&gt;` etc) with the default Java 8 JAXB implementation.

Sample code:

```java
package au.com.schreuder.moxy.test;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

public class Main {

    @XmlRootElement(name = "model")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    public static class Model {

        private String value;

        @XmlValue
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("moxy.test.main");

        Model model = new Model();
        model.setValue("<person><nickname>Jughead</nickname></person>");

        System.out.println(marshallFragment(model));
    }

    public static String marshallFragment(Object o)
            throws Exception {

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(o.getClass());
        System.out.println(context.getClass());
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        System.out.println(m.getClass());

        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        m.marshal(o, writer);

        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

And the complete dependencies from `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

XML does not require `>` to be escaped unless it appears as part of the sequence `]]>`. So both serializations are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Michael! I wasn't sure whether the trailing `>` characters needed to be escaped or not.

Comment: In our particular application we're trying to exactly reproduce the behaviour of another system where an XML payload is serialised and sent as the text content of an XML 'message' document. 

I got the serialisation working with the default JAXB implementation but then switched to MOXy to take advantage of the MOXy extensions for handling `null` values. 

Any hints on how I might persuade MOXy to encode `>` as `&gt;`?

Comment: With XML techologies, aiming for identical serialization is giving yourself loads of unnecessary complications. The key thing is that the XML should be canonically equivalent, not that it should be lexically identical. Two different XML serializers are always going to make different choices.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and trying to get our serialisation to match our sample data certainly has been a complicated process!

Unfortunately, we need to treat the client software we're communicating with as a black box and I can't assume that it will treat different serialisations identically, even if they're canonically equivalent. Sorry!

Comment: ... I did manage to find a solution using the default JAXB which I'll post in due course for future reference. Thanks for your help, Michael.

Comment: Does the default JAXB guarantee the order of attributes in the result? Often it's an accident of memory allocation in the JVM, and the fact that all your tests produce the same attribute order today doesn't mean they will still do so tomorrow.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to apologise for not taking my advice. I'll keep offering it anyway, if only because you're not the only person reading this thread.